# How I can mock response of Apollo Android

Tags: android, kotlin, apollo

I'm trying to mock response to my query but I can't because the builder needed and doesn't know how to pass operations?

Basicly I have network class like this :

```
 class NetworkService @Inject constructor(
   private val apolloClient: ApolloClient
    ) {

suspend fun <D : Operation.Data, T, V : Operation.Variables> suspendedQuery(
    query: Query<D, T, V>,
    cachePolicy: HttpCachePolicy.Policy = HttpCachePolicy.NETWORK_FIRST
): Resource<Response<T>> {

    val response = try {

        apolloClient.query(query)
            .toBuilder().httpCachePolicy(cachePolicy)
            .build()
            .await()

    } catch (e: ApolloException) {
        return Resource.error(e.localizedMessage)
    }
    return if (response.hasErrors()) {
        Resource.error(response.errors.toString())
    } else {
        Resource.success(response)
    }
 }
}
```

and  I want to mock the response returned from this function like this

I successed when I'm returning an error
`val expectedResponse = Resource.error<Response<MyQuery.Data>>("ERROR")`

But I have problem to mocking the resposne here:
`val expectedResponse = Resource.success<Response<MyQuery.Data>>(Response("Response.builder(Operation<>)"))`

I want to know How to build the inside the quote "Response.builder(Operation<>)"?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that this is a long running problem according to the [apollo-android issues list](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/issues). I can see that you've asked a similar question there also.

I found [this issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/issues/3028) which looks to be resolving this problem in the not too distant future. It was supposed to be this month but now looks like next.

So think this means that you're only solution right now is to use mock web server, and have it return a sample response to the client. This is how we have implemented our tests currently.

Comment: the reason that I don't want to mock the apollo client as a webserver as I need only to mock the response not the whole client

Comment: Yeah, I understood that. We wanted to do the same but the only way we could find to do it was using mock webserver and then pointing the client to it.